# Sitecore media library - unable to load large files ( > 8MB) via Azure Front Door

Tags: azure, media-library, cdn

We've run into an issue in Sitecore 9.3 where it's not serving media items properly via Azure FrontDoor with caching enabled. (Front Door works exceptionally well for 99.95% of the website).

But a 20MB PDF from the media library won't properly download, yet uploading it to the file system and loading it as a static PDF via Azure Front Door file will load correctly.

I have a feeling there's a glitch in the Sitecore media handler chunk capability (Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler).

Azure Front Door "Delivery of Large files": https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-caching

Front door downloads large files in 8MB chunks. It appears Sitecore media handler won't properly serve media items to Azure Front Door when they are > 8MB.

Has anyone run into this issue and been able to resolve it?

I opened a Sitecore ticket, but they can't dig much further into it because Azure Front Door isn't listed in the official support matrix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Front Door and Azure CDN use the [RFC-7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) implementation of Range header requests. ([Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-caching#delivery-of-large-files))

In Sitecore, the `Media.EnableRangeRetrievalRequest` setting is enabled by default. It is implemented based on [RFC-2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), but as far as I can tell RFC-7233 has superseded it and it looks like Sitecore has not updated the Range header handling to support the changes in RFC-7233. This is true as of Sitecore 10.0.

You can fix the issue by setting `Media.EnableRangeRetrievalRequest` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you Mark! It appears this completely explains the issue and setting the value to false resolves the PDF download errors occurring on large > 8MB files from the Sitecore Media Library.

Comment: Great find Mark.