# Browser is unable to load pdf documents from Azure CDN

Tags: sxa, azure-search, cdn

we are getting an error when the browser is trying to download pdf documents. we are getting an error i.e. `Failed to load the document`.

This error we are getting for pdf files that are greater than 8MB. Download is working in the same URL. Our pdf docs are available in Azure CDN.

Below is the example URL:
http://cdn-endpoint/-/media/Project/Site/shared/Attachments/New-Pdf.pdf?rev=-1&download=1

Comment: Did you try this solution https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/26167/2495 ?

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, This issue seems to be from Azure CDN side and not from sitecore side.

Comment: Did setting `Media.EnableRangeRetrievalRequest` to `false` make any difference?